# Use both Flask/Python API route and NodeJS API route with pages router

Tags: node.js, flask, next.js

I'm using a Python Flask API backend with my Next app according to [this](https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-use-python-and-javascript-in-the-same-application) article.

I'm using Next 12.3.4 (pages router).

The structure of my API is currently:

```
pages
--|api
----|__pycache__
----|index.py
```

`next.config.js`:

```
  async rewrites()
  {
      return [
          {
              source: '/api/:path*',
              destination:
              process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
                  ? 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/:path*'
                  : '/api/',
          }
      ]
  },
```

I want to add a new Node API route under the `pages/api/` folder, that I would be able to hit separately from the Python/Flask route.

For example, `await axios.post('/api/newNodeRoute')`.

Right now if I try this, I get a 404 error as it all seems to be going through my Python/Flask route. I've used Next API routes many times before, but never while combined with a Python/Flask backend, so I'm not sure how to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your python endpoints in a `py` folder and only rewrite for `/py` endpoints, I think others will default to the next.js node server.

```js
async rewrites()
  {
      return [
          {
              source: '/api/py/:path*',
              destination:
              process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
                  ? 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/:path*'
                  : '/api/py/:path*',
          }
      ]
  }
```